# wso2emm1.1.0 invalid keystore error

Tags: java, ios, wso2, keystore, wso2-iot

I have an error at item 8 https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/iOS+Server+Configurations:
I'm sure that my passwort is correct.

```
[root@localhost security]# keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ca.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore wso2emm.jks
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

I'm also getting a error by output information about the existing wso2emm.jks:

```
[root@localhost security]# keytool -list -v -keystore wso2emm.jks                                           keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:789)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
```

Is there an Error from the wso2 file? Anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first time you entered the wrong password. So delete that file and execute again this command. then will create new .jks file.
Give the new password and check it.

Comment: should I delete the original wso2emm.jks file? I think this is not the right way to fix the Problem?

Comment: @Jon: The wso2emm.jks contains only the CA and RA certificates. There fore you can go ahead and deleted the wso2emm.jks file. Then follow the instructions in the [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/iOS+Server+Configurations) to create a new wso2emm.jks.